# terraform: How to transform YAML list to dynamic resources

Tags: terraform

My apologies, data structures and algorithms is not my cup of tea. I have created a yaml list looking like this:

```yaml
---
clients:
  - name: "bank_of_braavos"
    services:
      - "HTTPS"
      - "DNS"
    cidr:
      - "127.0.0.1/32"
      - "127.0.0.2/32"
      - "127.0.0.3/32"
  - name: "tatooine"
    services:
      - "HTTPS"
      - "ICMP"
    cidr:
      - "958.xx.21.1r/aar"
      - "958.xx.21.1g/fwr"
```

Firstly, I think this YAML list is OK, my first idea was to use something like:

```
clients:
  bank_of_bravos:
    - cidr:...
```

Then I can just work with list of lists, rather than keys of random names. I think when I have a list of clients that will have different names, the first variant is more logical.

And what I want is to create dynamic resources in Terraform, specifically in FortiOS. This is not any provider specific, rather a terraform syntax question. I would like to use this one block and create resources with index something like `fortios_firewall_address.address["bank_of_bravos-127.0.0.1"]`

So there are three options what I can do with this yaml list when loading into terraform, not sure which one is correct but I think this map would be possible to work with:

```
locals {
  clients_config = yamldecode(file("clients.yml"))

  clients = {
    for client in local.clients_config.clients :
    client.name => {
      cidr     = client.cidr
      services = client.services
    }
  }
}
```

I am having problem how to actually access the values and iterate through them. The problem is also that I want to iterate over list inside another list. Something like this does not work:

```
resource "fortios_firewall_address" "clients" {
  for_each = { for client in local.clients : "${client.name}-${client.cidr}" => client }
  allow_routing        = "disable"
  name                 = "Client_${each.client.name}_${each.client.cidr}"
  subnet               = "${each.value.cidr}"
  type                 = "ipmask"
  visibility           = "enable"
}
```

EDIT: adding first few errors:

```
│ Error: Unsupported attribute                                                                                                                                                                               
│ 
│   on policy.tf line 15, in resource "fortios_firewall_address" "clients":
│   15:   for_each = { for client in local.clients : "${client.name}-${client.cidr}" => client }
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│ 
│   on policy.tf line 15, in resource "fortios_firewall_address" "clients":
│   15:   for_each = { for client in local.clients : "${client.name}-${client.cidr}" => client }
│ 
│ This object does not have an attribute named "name".
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
│ 
│   on policy.tf line 15, in resource "fortios_firewall_address" "clients":
│   15:   for_each = { for client in local.clients : "${client.name}-${client.cidr}" => client }
│     ├────────────────
│     │ client.cidr is tuple with 3 elements
│ 
│ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
```

Comment: What does "this does not work" mean? Are there any errors?

Comment: added first few errors

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. The simplest approach is probably to pre-process the `clients` data into a list of all the client-name/CIDR pairs in a `locals` block (which might be what you were attempting?)

```
locals {
  clients_config = yamldecode(file("clients.yml"))

  client_cidrs = flatten([
    for client in local.clients_config.clients : [
      for cidr in client.cidr : {
        name     = client.name
        cidr     = cidr
        services = client.services
      }
    ]
  ])
}
```

You can see the format of this processed list by just having the above code (without any Fortinet stuff), and add

```
output "processed" {
    value = local.client_cidrs
}
```

then just run `terraform plan`.

To use this processed list, you would then have

```
resource "fortios_firewall_address" "clients" {
  for_each = local.clients

  allow_routing        = "disable"
  name                 = "Client_${each.value.name}_${each.value.cidr}"
  subnet               = "${each.value.cidr}"
  type                 = "ipmask"
  visibility           = "enable"
}
```

I'm not sure how you're planning to use the `services` part. If you're not going to use it, then you can just drop it from the pre-processing block.

Comment: Does this work? Did not work for me. Also I do not see how will it not create duplicate resources if you iterate only over `local.clients_config.clients`.

Comment: Oh I see. No, this will not be quite right, and you will need to do some pre-processing in a `locals` block first. I'll update the answer in a moment.