# Having parsing map of list containing map inside in terraform

Tags: terraform, hashicorp-vault

My variable file is like below

```
 team_namespace = {
  namespace-team1 = [
    {
      group_name  = "group1"
      team_policy = "namespace-del.hcl"
    },
    {
      group_name  = "group2"
      team_policy = "namespace-eng.hcl"
   }
  ],
  namespace-team2 = [
    {
      group_name  = "group3"
      team_policy = "namespace-del.hcl"
    },
    {
      group_name  = "group4"
      team_policy = "namespace-eng.hcl"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
module "vault_policies" {
  for_each       = var.team_namespace
  source         = "./../../modules/vault-policies"
  team_name      = each.value.group_name
  team_namespace = each.key
  team_policy    = file(format("./policies/%s", each.value.team_policy))
  depends_on     = [module.vault_namespace]
}
```

My output is only showing group 1 resource but not group2,3,4

what can i do to make it work ?

I am expecting with each namespace I can assign multiple policy to AD group

Comment: You'll need to create a new variable in a `locals` block that holds a list of the complete set of policies that you want. You should be able to build that list automatically from the `team_namespace` map that you have. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750365/1198321) for some inspiration on how to write that conversion

Answer (score 0):

You have to **flatten** your variable:

```
locals {
  flat_team_namespace = merge([
    for namespace, teams in var.team_namespace: {
      for team in teams: 
        "${namespace}-${team.group_name}" => {
            namespace_name = namespace
            group_name =  team.group_name
            team_policy = team.team_policy
        }
   }
  ]...) # do NOT remove the dots
}
```

then

```
module "vault_policies" {
  for_each       = var.flat_team_namespace
  source         = "./../../modules/vault-policies"
  team_name      = each.value.group_name
  team_namespace = each.value.namespace_name
  team_policy    = file(format("./policies/%s", each.value.team_policy))
  depends_on     = [module.vault_namespace]
}
```