# Terraform. Add Cloudfront aliases(alternative domain names) to Route53 as a records

Tags: terraform, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have faced with a problem that I cant pass parameters in correct way from map to the aws_route53_records Terraform resource for creation DNS records, based on aliases (alternative domain names) for Cloudfront.

As a result I want to have a created records in route53 for Cloudfront aliases (alternative names).

dev.tfvars file

```
config = [
  {
    "id" : "f21",
    "clientName" : "A",
    "domain" : "development-a.my.domain.com",
    "aliases" : ["a1.my.domain.com", "a2.my.domain.com"],
    "route53ZoneId" : "XXXXXXXXX1"
  },
  {
    "id" : "f22",
    "clientName" : "B",
    "domain" : "development-b.my.domain.com",
    "aliases" : ["b1.my.domain.com", "b2.my.domain.com"],
    "route53ZoneId" : "XXXXXXXXX1"
  }
]
```

From main.tf (part for domain_name - works fine)

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "cf-record-domain-name" {
  for_each = { for each in var.config : each.id => each }

  zone_id = each.value.route53ZoneId
  name    = each.value.domain
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [
    aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[each.value.id].domain_name
  ]
}
```

Now, Im trying to do the same but for Cloudfront aliases:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "enterprise-web-dns-record-alias" {
  for_each = { for each in var.client_config : each.id => each }

  zone_id = each.value.route53ZoneId
  name    = each.value.aliases
  type    = "CNAME"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = [
  aws_cloudfront_distribution.main[each.value.id].domain_name
 ]
}
```

I suppose that I need to use "nested for_each" with "flatten", but I don't know how....
Any suggestion?

As a result I want to have a created records in route53 for Cloudfront aliases (alternative names).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [terraform: How to transform YAML list to dynamic resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76750125/terraform-how-to-transform-yaml-list-to-dynamic-resources)

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Comment: Which part of that answer doesn't help? You have a list of maps, each of which contains a list of items, and you need to convert that to a flat list to be used in a `for_each`, right? That's the same as that question, just with different item names.

Comment: Problem has been fixed